# Facebook Message To All Friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

Is there any way by which I can get all the friends using FB api and than message all of them.

Which approach is better to achieve it, a bot or using facebook api? 
If Bot, than which bot can be used as a kickstart, which programming language is preferred?

JAVA,ASP.NET

Comment: Would this be used to spam / hack accounts though?

Comment: _“Which approach is better to achieve it, a bot or using facebook api?”_ - neither. Bots are for communication between a page and a user. There is nothing for user-to-user conversation API-wise. _If_ anyone actually feels that they need to be that much of an annoying person (“message to all friends”), then they should do it via the Facebook UI. Don’t try and create an app for that, that will be considered spam from the very get-go.

Comment: I think Napster is looking for something like Facebook blaster.I don't think any facebook API exists which lets you send a message to a list of users.

Comment: I just want it to handel alerts, I have a facebook account in which all of my team members are, I want to provide them a single message. it's hards to add 100 friends in a messanger box etc.

Comment: @Nofi Yes I've checked it I want something like this but FB blaster has many restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get all friends - only those who authorized your App. Also, it is not possible to send a message to friends with the API, you can only use the Send Dialog and let the user specify the recipient on his own: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

What you want to achieve would be possible with a bot though. Users can register to get messages from the bot, so you can create an alert system with it. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/

It would be a general alert system though, not between friends. For that, i would recommend not using Facebook but Emails.

Comment: I believe it's a bot, could you please elaborate it to some extent ?

Comment: that´s not a messenger bot, that looks like a highly illegal spam tool. information about bots can be found in the second link of my answer, the docs about bots are pretty good. just go through "introduction" and "get started".

Comment: yeah, definitely not allowed. a lot of scraping, which is not allowed on facebook. don´t use it, and don´t create something like this.